# Website to view multiple survyes owned by multiple organizations using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, survey

I am developing a web site which will be used to enter, edit and check survey status. The client can log into this web site to his dashboard from which he can view survey status, enter new survey, edit a survey, etc.

Now I want to put each survey in a separate database which will be named as "surveyName"+SurveyDB. Since each Organization will have multiple users logging into the website I have decided to create a separate Database for the users which will contain the following:

Users table
Organizations table
OrganizationSurveyMapping Table

The Organization table will have the organization info in it. The users table will have user info and the organization that user belongs to. The OrganizationSurveyMapping table is a Many-to-Many table that maps each organization to its surveys, the name of the survey is the name of database in which the survey resides. This name will be used to make a connection to the database.

My question is: Am I doing it right? Is it OK to have each survey in separate Database? Is there a better way?

Comment: i wouldnt use a seperate database per survey. Table would be a better aproach.

Comment: But each survey is made of many tables. Plus, having each survey in a separate mdf file means it is isolated from other surveys.

Answer (score 1):

Having separate Database? I don't think its a good approach. Wondering if there are 1000s of surveys, there will be thousands of DB's.

Possible solution:
1. Multiple tables : "surveyName"+User (still I don't think it would be a good approach)
2. Referential data (this is the best approach I can think, you just need to normalize nicely)

Also it doesn't make much sense "having each survey in a separate mdf file means it is isolated from other surveys."
If above is the case then How CMS works? in CMS like Kentico etc we can create multiple sites, that means they will create new DB? They don't. It's all about referential data integrity.

Comment: So you are suggesting a single database that will hold all surveys and then I can get any Survey info by using the keys?! BTW: in wordpress you need to create a new database to make a new website in local installations, I have no idea how they do it in wordpress.com

Comment: Yes.
If you are familiar with ORM than you can also go with that. Fluent nhibernate is one of the ORM you can work with.